# Canvas convert SVG to PNG doesn't get the full size

Tags: canvas, svg, d3.js

I have big SVG image it about 200 (orgchart of company > 50 department). Example info is:

```
SVGRect {height: 270, width: 1600, y: 0, x: -150}
```

and I want to export with size image depend on this size of SVG. Here is my code when export

```
export_svg: function () {
            var html = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("version", '1.1')
                .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
                .node().parentNode.innerHTML
            var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html)

            var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
                context = canvas.getContext("2d")
            // clear cache previous
            canvas.width = $('svg')[0].getBBox().width
            canvas.height = $('svg')[0].getBBox().height
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var image = new Image
            image.src = imgsrc
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
            var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1)

            d3.select("#export_svg").attr('href', canvasdata)
            d3.select("#export_svg").attr('download', 'Org Chart.png')


        },
```

Is that coordinator of SVG related here?

[image: SVG Org chart]

When I export to PNG it can't get full size of org chart

[image: Export PNG]

Comment: You are using the width and height returned from calling `getBBox()` on the `<svg>` element.  That isn't necessarily the same as the width and height of the rendered SVG.  The two coordinate systems don't necessarily have the same scale.  Even if they do, you will also need to account for the `x` and `y` components of the BBox as well.

Comment: How about ignore coordinate and just get only svg and convert to canvas?
Is that possible to do that?

Comment: No. You need to render it to the canvas.  Try setting your SVG width and height to the same size as your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to change context.drawImage(image, 0, 0); to context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);)